# After Build, all my text content is centered on Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, yarnpkg, bootstrap-vue

I'm having a issue when I build my project!
All my `<p>` tag become centered after Build and on Dev instance, they stay on Left side...
Example:

```
<div class="pt-3">
        <h4>Forma de acesso:</h4>
        <p>Certificado Digital (Token) <i>OU</i></p>
        <p>CPF e Senha</p>
      </div>
```

On dev server:
[image]

On live server (after build):
[image]

Any advice of why is this happening?
If helps, I'm using Bootstrap-Vue and yarn to build project!

Edit: using `text-left` class not work, text keeps centered.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Does your browser's developer console show any differences?

Comment: My dev console is clean, no errors.. nothing there.

Comment: Why not inspect the styles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used a `text-center` on my html css on App.vue...
My mistake.